# How can I echo Laravel table values in Many_to_Many relationship table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, manytomanyfield

please I need help on this my Laravel project. So, I've a Many_to_Many relationship tables of users, group and group_user. In the system I'm working on, a user can create group by selecting a number of other registered users. My users table has id, first_name last_name and email columns, which I want to be able to access on my Group index page.

Group model

```
public function users () {
     return this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

Users model

```
public function groups () {
     return this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
    }
```

groupController

```
(...)->with('groups', Group::all())
->with('users', User::all());
```

group.blade.php

```
@foreach($groups as $group)
      @foreach($group->users as $user)
         {{$user->email}} 
      @endforeach  
    @endforeach
```

I expect to see the email address of the user with the current id on the group page but it's not coming

Comment: `->with('groups', Group::all())` where did you see that syntax? If you're trying to include your `groups` and `users` Relationships, it would simply be `->with('groups')` or `->with('users')`

Comment: 1. Groups “hasMany” users and users “belongsTo” many groups 2. $groups = Group::all(); everything else seems fine.